# Delete records which have more than N entries

Tags: sqlite, history, sql-delete

I have a table called `history`,
which has three columns.
`id`, `value`, `timestamp`

`Id` is not a primary key, but the pair `(id, timestamp)` is unique.
What I would like to do is delete all the older records for a specific ID that exceed a certain limit.
For example if i have these values:

```
-1,value1,1
-1,value2,2
-1,value3,3
-2,value4,4
-2,value5,5
-2,value6,6
```

And the limit is 2. After executing the statement i should get something like:

```
-1,value2,2
-1,value3,3
-2,value4,4
-2,value5,5
-2,value6,6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have it (tried and works for the testcases i had), the answer is:

```
DELETE  FROM history WHERE id = ?1 AND timestamp NOT in (SELECT sourcetime  FROM    history   WHERE   id =?1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT ?2);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM ... WHERE timestamp < ...
```

Doesn't work ?

Comment: No, timestamp is not the discrimination factor. I need to leave the NEWEST N records for a specified ID. I am not eliminating older than, i am eliminating for a specific ID the oldest members which exceed the desired limit for this ID.